# How to change any bit

Tags: c++

I have a text that is translated into 5 bit form. How to replace some bits, then output text with the changed bitss? Here my text Hello outputs 01000 00101 01100 01100 01111 It is necessary to replace any bit with the opposite one and then enter the text that we changed in bit form

This code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
 

std::string toBinary(std::string const &str) {
    std::string binary = "";
    for (char const &c: str) {
        binary += std::bitset<5>(c).to_string() + ' ';
    }
    return binary;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello world";
 
    std::string binary = toBinary(str);
    std::cout << binary << std::endl;
    
   
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to get a `char` from the `std::bitset<5>` ?

Comment: " to replace any bit with the opposite one" do you want to replace all or just one bit ?

Comment: `^ std::bitset<5>{0x1f};`

Comment: Replace all bits

Comment: `auto flipped = ~std::bitset<5>(c);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

std::string toString(std::string binary1)
{
    // use an array to store each letter's representation separately
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < binary1.length())
    {
        std::string x = "";
        while (binary1[i] != ' ')
        {
            x += binary1[i];
            i++;
        }
        arr.push_back(x);
        i++;
    }

    // convert the bits back to string
    std::string binary2 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == "00000")
        {
            binary2 += " ";
        }
        else
            binary2 += char(std::bitset<5>(arr[i]).to_ulong() + 64);
    }

    return binary2;
}

std::string toBinary(std::string const &str)
{
    std::string binary = "";
    for (char const &c : str)
    {
        binary += std::bitset<5>(c).to_string() + ' ';
    }
    return binary;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello world";

    std::string binary1 = toBinary(str);
    std::cout << binary1 << std::endl;

    // change certain bits
    // for instance, we're changing the first bit and the 9th bit;
    std::string str1, str2;
    str1 = str2 = binary1;
    str1[0] = '1';
    str2[9] = '1';

    std::cout << toString(str1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << toString(str2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
01000 00101 01100 01100 01111 00000 10111 01111 10010 01100 00100 
XELLO WORLD
HGLLO WORLD
```

Comment: And if the text is more than two words? He won't change everything.